# How to create QR / NFC tags for iOS AppClips

Tags: ios14, apple-appclips

Apple introduced [AppClips](https://developer.apple.com/app-clips/) with a lot of [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips).

One of the options to invoke this AppClip is by scanning a QR code, here's a sample from Apple:

[image: AppClip Code]

However, I can't find any info on how to create these kinds of codes.

Where can I find this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating **App Clip Codes** is now available through [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/login/) or using an [App Clip Code Generator](https://developer.apple.com/app-clips/resources/) tool.

More information can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/creating_app_clip_codes

Comment: Do you know if there are any 3rd party tools for generating those nice looking round QR codes to be used in a webpage. Like JS or PHP?

Answer (score 1):

The image in the question is not of a QR code but of an Apple proprietary equivalent that will probably be released later this year with the new iPhones.

As of **September 15th, 2020**, [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/app-clips/):

> Tools for creating these new codes will be available later this year.

Answer (score 1):

I developed an AppClip, first, I used a legacy QR code like this, it performs well:
[image]

NFC / QR code contain url as an input for your AppClip, then I handled it via `NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb`

```swift
MyMainAppView()
    .onContinueUserActivity(NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb, perform:  { userActivity in
      ActivityHandler.handleUserActivity(userActivity, routerState: self.history ?? nil)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

As of your example image, APPLE will release tools later this year to create these. NFC and QR codes you can create normally, as per my information since if you see WWDC video they are simple URL links embedded